# x86 assembly searching word in text file

Tags: string, search, assembly, x86, cpu-word

```
.data   
word           db 64 dup(?)          
wordLen         dw ?
```

Theres following code:

```
    MOV ah, 3Ch                     
    MOV cx, 0                       
    MOV dx, offset rez              
    INT 21h                         
    JC  writeWrror      
    MOV rFail, ax                   

    MOV counter, 0                  
    mov tcounter, 0

;*****************************************************
;Reading from file
;*****************************************************

  read:
    MOV bx, dFail           
    CALL    readBuf         
    CMP ax, 0               
    JE  closeWrite

;*****************************************************
;Compare tasks
;*****************************************************
    MOV cx, ax
    MOV si, offset skBuf
    MOV di, offset wrBuf
compare:      
  MOV   dl, [si]  
  mov temp, si
  mov si, counter
  mov dh, [zodis + si] 
  mov si, temp           
  CMP dl, dh
  JE isEqual
  mov counter, 0
tesk:
  INC   si
  LOOP  compare
```

Word is the word read from program parameters. I want to compare first symbol of my word with symbol read from file and continue reading by increasing counter if there is a match.

Is this compare legal operation to find a specified string in file? Or should i use other tactics?

Comment: _"Moving [word + counter] to dh throws error"_ That doesn't really tell us anything. What error are you getting _exactly_?

Comment: wrong parameters or addressing

Comment: Ok, well, you haven't showed how `word` and `counter` are declared. It's possible that the assembler wants you to explicitly state the size, e.g. `mov dh, byte ptr [word + counter]`. But if you expect `[word + counter]` to read from _the address of `word`_ + _the value of `counter`_ you're mistaken. There's no such addressing mode on the x86. You'd have to move the value of the counter into an appropriate register first.

Comment: Thats it. And it also could be misinterpreted, because word explicitely is a keyword.

Comment: Is it legal compare function? Or should i use another tactics to find a matching string?